WSL 2 update running into issues
So when I'm trying to run sudo apt update on my WSL 2 terminal, the following info prompted me:
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [128 kB]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Get:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease [18.1 kB]
Ign:6 https://pkg.wslutiliti.es/debian jammy InRelease
Get:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [23.8 kB]
Err:8 https://pkg.wslutiliti.es/debian jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 139.162.37.22 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://pkg.wslutiliti.es/debian jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I installed WSLView a few days ago and changed some settings in the repository so that I can manage to install it. Now everytime I try to run sudo apt update I always get these bunch of messages. Is there a way to fix it?

the issue is that pkg.wslutiliti.es has no jammy dist ... only real debian ones

yeah figured that out. Turned out they have an installation specifically for ubuntu

Resolved this issue by deleting wslu.list
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wslu.list

